# Count number of items above zero in PivotTable

Tags: excel, pivot-table

Lets say I have the following data for a project in Excel:

[image]

In the PivotTable, I'd like to count the number of tasks for each project that are delayed, i.e. the **number of tasks that has days of delay > 0**

I have tried:

[image]

But the result I get is this:

[image]

How do I count the number of tasks that have days of delay > 0 ?

Comment: Can you modify your SOURCE data? Can you add a column into your source data?

Comment: That is of course an option, but I would rather have the result only in the PivotTable

Comment: @Malin Have you tried the answer provided?

Answer (score 0):

Add `DAYS OF DELAY` as a filter\page field in to the pivot table then filter by it *(See figures below)*.

[image]

*Fig. 1*

[image]

*Fig. 2*